# ASP.NET Form not sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email

I am trying to make a form send an email to myself, but for some reason it is not working, and I can't figure out why.

When I submit the form it displays the stack trace of:

> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at emailform.index.send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Projects\emailform\emailform\index.aspx.cs:line 28

Anyone have any ideas?

I just started learning **C# and ASP.NET**, so it could probably be something obvious.

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="emailform.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br /> <br />
        <table align="center" width="60%">
            <tr>
                <td>to:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="to" runat="server" Text="email@gmail.com" width="60%" ></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>from:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="from" runat="server" Text="myemail@outlook.com" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>subject</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="subject" runat="server" Text="TEST" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>body</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="body" runat="server" Text="this is a test message" Height="30%" Width="60%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="send" onClick="send_Click" runat="server" Text="send" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="status" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace emailform
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(to.Text, from.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@outlook.com", "mypassword");
                client.Send(message);
                status.Text = "Message sent successfully!";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                status.Text = ex.StackTrace;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the entire exception message?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a trouble with your `SmtpClient` setting.

You use port 25 and SSL.

But by default port 25 do not use SSL encryption. Please review next [link](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use) for details.

Try to change your code like it:

```
client.EnableSsl = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I Tried Your Code and there is nothing wrong with your code.

I think you are entering Wrong Network Credential.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change This

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(to.Text, from.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);
```

To This

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);
```

It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

The library checks if it's a real email as well, submit a real possible email.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you're either using wrong port number or wrong credential settings:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
```

Try modifying server name and port number for SSL/TLS so that it looks like this:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);

// alternative
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
```

Additionally because you're using custom credentials, it is necessary to turn off default credential option before adding your own:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Finally, the complete `SmtpClient` code to send e-mail should be like example below:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@outlook.com", "mypassword");
client.Send(message);
```

References:

[Sending email in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/tr-TR/83a7c2fd-42c9-43be-88dd-8b23cb87c3db/c-smtpmailoutlookcom?forum=csharptr)

[Send mail to outlook account ASP.Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505394/send-mail-to-outlook-account-asp-net-c-sharp)